# Only with a double click does the event occur

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, onclick

button Uptade

```
    <button type="button" id="custom-icon" onclick="UpdateParents()"">Update</button>
```

function AJAX

```
function UpdateParents() {
var ParentsOBJ = { IDkids: $("#IDkids").val(), NameKids: $("#NameKids").val(), LastNameKids: $("#LastNameKids1").val(), NameFather: $("#NameFather").val(), NameMother: $("#NameMother").val(), PhoneMother: $("#PhoneMother").val(), PhoneFather: $("#PhoneFather").val() };
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/api/Parents/" + ParentsOBJ.IDkids,
    data: JSON.stringify(ParentsOBJ),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        Parents = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#custom-icon').on('click',function () {
            swal({ title: "update", text: "ok.", icon: "/up.jpg" });
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 2000);
        });
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }

});
```

**$('#custom-icon').on('click',function ()** 
 Only when I double-click the button does the operation take place.
I can understand why this is happening (click in click),
But can't solve the problem.
I will be happy to resolve!!!

Comment: So now we need to understand what are you want to do, first click you want to trigger ajax call to get Parents, and after that you bind another click event(B) to button, so after this, if user click button again, are you still want to trigger ajax call or just event B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you double bind the `$('#custom-icon')`, and the 2nd bind takes place inside an `ajax` success `callback`, which takes in place only after the `ajax` request that has been triggered from the first click has been finished.

All you need to do is to remove the 2nd binding, as it's unnecessary because you already bind the `click` event from the `html`, your new code will look like this:

```
function UpdateParents() {
var ParentsOBJ = { IDkids: $("#IDkids").val(), NameKids: $("#NameKids").val(), LastNameKids: $("#LastNameKids1").val(), NameFather: $("#NameFather").val(), NameMother: $("#NameMother").val(), PhoneMother: $("#PhoneMother").val(), PhoneFather: $("#PhoneFather").val() };
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/api/Parents/" + ParentsOBJ.IDkids,
    data: JSON.stringify(ParentsOBJ),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        Parents = JSON.parse(data);
        swal({ title: "update", text: "ok.", icon: "/up.jpg" });
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, 2000);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }

});
```

A better practice here would be to accept a `callback` method from the `UpdateParents` function, and then pass the `success` as a callback.